# Rendering only authorized (Devise) user data in Rails without excess empty space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, authorization, erb

I am trying to create a todo app that will allow the user to create lists and then "todo" items under each list. However, I want each user to *only* be able to see his or her lists. While I've been able to partially solve it using the `current_user` helper, the index page shows *empty space* where the other users lists are hidden.

[image: What it looks like in the browser]

Below please find the code for the index.html.erb page inside my todo_lists views.

```
<% @todo_lists.each do |todo_list| %>
  <div class="index_row clearfix">
    <% if todo_list.user == current_user %>
        <h2 class="todo_list_title"><%= link_to todo_list.title, todo_list %></h2>
        <p class="todo_list_sub_title"><%= todo_list.description %></p>
        <p><%= todo_list.user.first_name %></p>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>


<div class="links">
  <%= link_to "New Todo List", new_todo_list_path %>
</div>
```

Here's my repo on Github, in case you need to see more of the code: https://github.com/jramoscolon/todo

Is there a way to hide these empty spaces, as well as the non-matching todo items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your current view code, you are indiscriminately emitting `<div class="index_row clearfix">` elements, even when the `todo_list.user` does not match the `current_user`.  Simply move the whole`<div>` outside the `current_user` check, like so:

```
<% @todo_lists.each do |todo_list| %>
  <% if todo_list.user == current_user %>
    <div class="index_row clearfix">
        <h2 class="todo_list_title"><%= link_to todo_list.title, todo_list %></h2>
        <p class="todo_list_sub_title"><%= todo_list.description %></p>
        <p><%= todo_list.user.first_name %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This way, all of those empty `<div>` elements aren't included on the page.  This should clean up all that empty space.

Answer (score 0):

If your index view is user specific than the instance variable you want should be user specific as well.

Instead of `@todo_lists = ToDoList.all`

Use the `current_user.todo_lists` functionality supplied by your has_many/belongs to